# I can't customize my Logitech Mx Master 3 for Blender 3.5

Tags: mouse

I use logitech mx master 3 I customized my mouse buttons for Blender. I was using it Blender 3.4.1 and there wasn't any problem. But it doesn't work on 3.5.

Logitech Options app is updated. I downloaded 3.4 again for test and everything works perfect. But it doesn't still work on 3.5. Do you know how can i fix it or do you have same problem?

Thanks

Comment: There are no Blender developers here. Report it as a bug via the Help > Report a Bug menu in Blender.

Comment: Thanks for answer